# Does seeking an HTML5 video require loading the whole file?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to randomly seek to different points in a ~30 minute video every 30 seconds. The filesize will be 100mb. When I seek does the player start loading from that point or does it have to load the entire file and then find that time within it?

Comment: based on [this](http://blog.grio.com/2012/08/how-to-seek-an-html5-video-at-a-specific-time-on-load.html) it seems like you can, **if** the video metadata has been loaded, so the browser already knows the video size so it can ask the server to start loading from a different position, **and** the server knows how to honour partial data transfer requests. The fastest way to find out, of course, is to simply give it a try on a test URL and see what happens for your setup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the browser. If we are talking about a modern browser then when you seek, they will typically send a new http request to the server containing a `Range:` header, indicating what "chunk" of the file they want to load. This would only be for a browser utilizing http 1.1 or higher. I think if the browser supports html5 video then you can be fairly certain that they will be using http 1.1. Keep in mind though that the client will typically always be loading *something*. So if you seek to 5 seconds into the vid it will essentially start loading the entire thing again until another seek happens.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 isn't the issue... everything supports HTTP/1.1.  The problem is whether or not the client can determine what range to request (not always possible, especially for problematic formats).  It's not uncommon for a client to "needle drop".  It knows the overall file size based on the initial response headers and it should know how long the video is in time based on some container format headers.  It will often guess as to where the user is seeking and try to decode from there.  The problem is that with lossy formats, bitrates aren't always constant so the timing is not that accurate.

Comment: The other issue here is whether or not the server supports range requests.  You can support HTTP/1.1 just fine and not handle Range requests. In fact, this is very common, particularly when people are writing their own code to serve media without realizing what all they need to handle.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. The sever needs to be able to handle range headers for both sides to have the desired effect. I was assuming the context was a typical web server like lighttpd or nginx, but if it's custom server code then that is definitely a factor to consider

Answer (score 1):

No, it starts loading from the given timestamp, as long as the browser knows the duration of the video.